# How to build cordova node.js app using CircleCI to generate APK,IPA and broswer build

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, circleci-2.0

I have Node.JS code and i want to build cordova node.js app using CircleCI to generate APK,IPA and broswer build ,so how to write config.yml file for the same.

Furthermore, I have written config.yml file for android build but still it fails to generate APK file. 
So please let me know what is wrong.

My config.yml code:
For Broswer

```
steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: update-npm
          command: 'sudo npm install -g npm@latest'
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run:
          name: install-npm-wee
          command: npm install
      - run:
         name: install-cordova
         command: sudo npm install -g cordova
      - run:
         name: add-cordova
         command: cordova platform add browser@5.0.1 -save
      - run:
         name: build-browser
         command: cordova build browser       
      - run:
         name: mkdir-browser
         command: mkdir mybuild
      - store_artifacts:
          path: '/home/circleci/mern-starter/mybuild'
```

For Android :

```
 steps:
          - checkout
          - run:
              name: update-npm
              command: 'sudo npm install -g npm@latest'
          - restore_cache:
              key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          - run:
              name: install-npm-wee
              command: npm install
          - run:
             name: install-cordova
             command: sudo npm install -g cordova
          - run:
             name: add-cordova
             command: cordova platform add android
          - run:
             name: build-android
             command: cordova build android       
          - run:
             name: mkdir-android
             command: mkdir mybuild
          - store_artifacts:
              path: '/home/circleci/mern-starter/mybuild/myapk.apk'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error do you get ?